# If/else returning the wrong value in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This seems somewhat simple but I can't seem to get this working correctly. I have a method with a simple if/else statement based upon a ENV

```
def auth_credentials
  if ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'testenv1' || 'testenv2' || 'testenv3'
    { key: 'key1', secret: 'secret1' }
  elsif ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == "testenv4"
    { key: 'key2', secret: 'secret2' }
  else
    raise 'Unable to set key/secret'
  end
end
```

So in my console I type `ENV['ENVIRONMENT']` and I get `testenv4` returned. However when I then try to get the relevant key

```
auth_credentials[:key]
```

I get `key1` returned and not `key2` as expected..

Any reason for this ? Have U done something ridiculously silly?

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'testenv1' || 'testenv2' || 'testenv3'
```

is equivalent to:

```
(ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'testenv1') || 'testenv2' || 'testenv3'
```

so it always returns `true` or `'testenv2'`, which are both truthy.

Instead, you should have:

```
if %w(testenv1 testenv2 testenv3).include? ENV['ENVIRONMENT']
```

Answer (score 3):

Each compare needs to be separate, e.g.,

```
if (ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'testenv1') || (ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'testenv2') || (ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'testenv3')
```

You probably want to use a `case`, though, e.g.,

```
case ENV['ENVIRONMENT']
when 'testenv1', 'testenv2', 'testenv3'
  # Do this
else
  # Do that
end
```

(Or Marek's `include` idea.)

I favor a further step; regactoring the logic into communicative methods, e.g.,

```
if test_environment?
  # Do this
elsif super_secrect_test_environment?
  # Do that
else
  # Do the other thing
end
```